# Como gerar um arquivo JSON com todos os elementos de um array em Python

Tags: python, json

Estou tentando inserir o nome e a média de todos os usuários em um arquivo JSON, no caso é para ser inseridos todos os valores que estão nos dois vetores, porem somente o ultimo valor é inserido.
Meu codigo:

```
import json

QuantidadeAlunos = int(input("Digite a quantidade de alunos: "))
NomesAlunos = [0] * QuantidadeAlunos
Media = [0] * QuantidadeAlunos

for i in range(QuantidadeAlunos):
    NomesAlunos[i] = input("Digite o nome do aluno de numero : ")
    Media[i] = float(input("Digite a media do respectivo aluno: "))

for j in range(QuantidadeAlunos):
    Alunos = {
        "alunos": [{
            "Nome": NomesAlunos[j],
            "Media": Media[j]
        }]
    }


with open("Alunos.json", "w") as arquivo:     
    json.dump(Alunos, arquivo, indent=4)
```

O resultado que eu espero é esse que foi feito manualmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso o "Marcos foi inserido primeiro com sua respectiva média e depois o Carlos com sua respectiva média, porem o resultado que obtenho é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Independentemente do tamanho do vetor só fica no arquivo jSON o ultimo usuário inserido no input e sua respectiva média.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

O que acontece no seu código é que cada vez que ele entra no for, o dicionário Alunos é sobrescrito e por isso você só tem os dados do último aluno nele.

Sugiro inicializar o dicionário no início do código com uma chave "alunos" e uma lista vazia como valor.
E no for, você adiciona itens à lista, ficando assim:

```
import json

QuantidadeAlunos = int(input("Digite a quantidade de alunos: "))
NomesAlunos = [0] * QuantidadeAlunos
Media = [0] * QuantidadeAlunos
alunos = {"alunos": []}

for i in range(QuantidadeAlunos):
    NomesAlunos[i] = input("Digite o nome do aluno de numero : ")
    Media[i] = float(input("Digite a media do respectivo aluno: "))

for j in range(QuantidadeAlunos):
    alunos["alunos"].append(
        {
            "Nome": NomesAlunos[j],
            "Media": Media[j]
        }
    )


with open("Alunos.json", "w") as arquivo:     
    json.dump(alunos, arquivo, indent=4)
```